# Knockout component data bind from jquery

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to call component from js file and append it to body? For example this is my code :

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function ($, ko) {

        ko.components.register('page1', {
            require: 'App/Controllers/page1'
        })
        ko.applyBindings();

        $('#body').html('<page1></page1>');
    })
```

But component doesn't load. If  tag  is inside regular html it works fine

Comment: Change the order. First is `$('#body').html('<page1></page1>')` only then `ko.applyBindings()`. Otherwise, Knockout wouldn't be able to find anything to bind your component to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1. First add the html element, then apply binding.

   ```
   $('#body').html('<page1></page1>');
   ko.applyBindings();
   ```
2. Add the html element and then apply bindings to it as a descendent.

   ```
   ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(viewModel,element);
   ```